# Armadillo cpp: access slice of a 3D field

Tags: c++, armadillo

I am working with armadillo in c++ and I've come across the following problem:
given a 3D field class, I cannot access individual slices of it. 
Here a small piece of code to illustrate it:

```
//Define field with chosen dimensions
field<mat> Test_field(2,2,2);

//Fill it with 2x2 random matrices in each position
for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
  for (int j=0;j<2;j++){
    for (int k=0;k<2;k++){
      Test_field(i,j,k)=randu(2,2);
       }}}

//Display results
cout<<Test_field<<endl;
cout<<Test_field.slice(0)<<endl;
cout<<Test_field.slice(1)<<endl;
```

What happens when I compile and execute this code is that I see:

1. The field correctly displayed.
2. The first slice of it.
3. The first slice of it again.

Am I doing something wrong?
Can anybody help?
Thanks in advance!

Sergio

Comment: it should be already fixed in the new version `8.300.1` released today :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and help =) I'd need to read it a couple of times again, since I'm quite a beginner in cpp, but it was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, it looks like a bug in Armadillo...

When you call the `slice` function, Armadillo (version 8.300.0) creates a `subview_field` (the last parameter signifies the total number of slices one is interested in):

```
template<typename oT>
inline
subview_field<oT>
field<oT>::slice(const uword slice_num)
  {
  arma_extra_debug_sigprint();

  arma_debug_check( (slice_num >= n_slices), "field::slice(): out of bounds" );

  return subview_field<oT>(*this, 0, 0, slice_num, n_rows, n_cols, 1);
  }
```

Now, when a `subfield_view` is created, it stores the requested number of slices in `n_slices`, and the "slice-offset" in `aux_slice1`:

```
template<typename oT>
arma_inline
subview_field<oT>::subview_field
  (
  const field<oT>& in_f,
  const uword      in_row1,
  const uword      in_col1,
  const uword      in_slice1,
  const uword      in_n_rows,
  const uword      in_n_cols,
  const uword      in_n_slices
  )
  : f(in_f)
  , aux_row1(in_row1)
  , aux_col1(in_col1)
  , aux_slice1(in_slice1)
  , n_rows(in_n_rows)
  , n_cols(in_n_cols)
  , n_slices(in_n_slices)
  , n_elem(in_n_rows*in_n_cols*in_n_slices)
  {
  arma_extra_debug_sigprint();
  }
```

As an example, this simplified program then prints `1 1` as expected.

```
#include <armadillo>
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    arma::field<double> F(1,1,3);

    for (int k=0;k<3;k++){
        F(0,0,k) = 100*k;
    }

    auto s = F.slice(1);
    std::cout << s.n_slices << '\t' << s.aux_slice1 << '\t' << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Let's now try to modify this slice:

```
#include <armadillo>
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    arma::field<double> F(1,1,3);

    for (int k=0;k<3;k++){
        F(0,0,k) = 100*k;
    }

    std::cout << F << std::endl;
    auto s = F.slice(1);
    s.fill(42);
    std::cout << F << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However, this produces:

```
[field slice 0]
[field column 0]
0


[field slice 1]
[field column 0]
100


[field slice 2]
[field column 0]
200



[field slice 0]
[field column 0]
42


[field slice 1]
[field column 0]
100


[field slice 2]
[field column 0]
200
```

So Armadillo modified slice `0` of the original field rather than the selected slice number `1`. The reason for this seems to be that the `fill` method behaves differently when the subfield has only one slice:

```
template<typename oT>
inline
void
subview_field<oT>::fill(const oT& x)
  {
  arma_extra_debug_sigprint();

  subview_field<oT>& t = *this;

  if(t.n_slices == 1)
    {
    for(uword col=0; col < t.n_cols; ++col)
    for(uword row=0; row < t.n_rows; ++row)
      {
      t.at(row,col) = x;
      }
    }
  else
    {
    for(uword slice=0; slice < t.n_slices; ++slice)
    for(uword col=0;   col   < t.n_cols;   ++col  )
    for(uword row=0;   row   < t.n_rows;   ++row  )
      {
      t.at(row,col,slice) = x;
      }
    }
  }
```

since it calls the 2-argument version of the `at` method:

```
template<typename oT>
arma_inline
oT&
subview_field<oT>::at(const uword in_row, const uword in_col)
  {
  const uword index = (in_col + aux_col1)*f.n_rows + aux_row1 + in_row;

  return *((const_cast< field<oT>& >(f)).mem[index]);
  }
```

which completely ignores the "slice-offset" stored in `aux_slice1`. This offset is correctly taken into account in the 3-argument version of the `at` method:

```
template<typename oT>
arma_inline
oT&
subview_field<oT>::at(const uword in_row, const uword in_col, const uword in_slice)
  {
  const uword index = (in_slice + aux_slice1)*(f.n_rows*f.n_cols) + (in_col + aux_col1)*f.n_rows + aux_row1 + in_row;

  return *((const_cast< field<oT>& >(f)).mem[index]);
  }
```

To illustrate this, let's modify the sample program above to:

```
auto s = F.slices(1, 2);
s.fill(42);
```

Then the output is as expected:

```
[field slice 0]
[field column 0]
0


[field slice 1]
[field column 0]
42


[field slice 2]
[field column 0]
42
```

Similar "effect" affects other methods in `include/armadillo_bits/subview_field_meat.hpp` as well...